# set foucs on a feedback component with Apache Wicket

Tags: wicket-1.6

How can I add a focus  behavior to a feedback component in a panel?

Searching leads to very little information, mostly on setting the default field. I do not want to set a default field, rather I am looking to set focus

Answer (score 0):

You could focus a Component by using `AjaxRequestTarget.focusComponent(feedbackPanel)`.

There are two preconditions for this to work:

- the HTML element used for the FeedbackPanel has to be focusable, i.e. to have a `tabindex` attribute
- the HTML element used for the FeedbackPanel has to have an `id` attribute (`feedbackPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true)`), so that Wicket Ajax can look it up and set the focus on it